# Match HTML tags in two strings using regex in Python

Tags: python, html, regex

I want to verify that the HTML tags present in a source string are also present in a target string.

For example:

```
>> source = '<em>Hello</em><label>What's your name</label>'
>> verify_target(’<em>Hi</em><label>My name is Jim</label>')
True
>> verify_target('<label>My name is Jim</label><em>Hi</em>')
True
>> verify_target('<em>Hi<label>My name is Jim</label></em>')
False
```

Comment: match monkey and stars and deco_hand_frog using ratchet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would get rid of Regex and look at [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).
`findAll(True)` lists all the tags found in your source.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
allTags = soup.findAll(True)
[tag.name for tag in allTags ]
[u'em', u'label']
```

then you just need to remove possible duplicates and confront your tags lists.

This snippet verifies that ALL of source's tags are present in target's tags.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
def get_tags_set(source):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
    all_tags = soup.findAll(True)
    return set([tag.name for tag in all_tags])

def verify(tags_source_orig, tags_source_to_verify):
    return tags_source_orig == set.intersection(tags_source_orig, tags_source_to_verify)

source= '<label>What\'s your name</label><label>What\'s your name</label><em>Hello</em>'
source_to_verify= '<em>Hello</em><label>What\'s your name</label><label>What\'s your name</label>'
print verify(get_tags_set(source),get_tags_set(source_to_verify))
```

Comment: Yepp. You definitely want to use BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that regex is the right way here, basically because html is not always just a string, but it's a bit more complex, with nested tags.

I suggest you to use [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html), create a class with parses the original source and builds a structure on it. Then verify that the same data structure is valid for the targets to be verified.